# Access private field of a instance object

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a class, which has one field named `orbits` (it has the same type as my class `Body` and has the `private` modifier):

```
public class Body {

     // I defined it as private field
     private Body orbits = null;

     public Body getOrbits(){
         return orbits;
     }

     public void setOrbits(Body orbits){
    this.orbits = orbits;
     }

     public void capture(Body victim){
        //Why 'victim' can access 'orbits' ?
        victim.orbits = this;
     }
}
```

In the class, I defined a method named `capture(Body victim)`, which has one parameter with type `Body`. I am wondering in the method why I can directly access the `private` field `orbits` of instance `victim` ? I mean the field is `private` , isn't it non-accessible through the instance victim?

Comment: It's because it is manipulated within *the same* class. Be it different classes, it won't be accessible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Privacy is not per instance - it's per class.

The class can access the private fields of all instances.

For example, the method `equals( Object o )` can cast o (if appropriate) to the same type, and compare its private members with the object on which equals() was called.

Comment: Do you mean if I define the capture(Body victim) method in a class other than Body, then the victim can not access orbits, right?

Comment: If the method capture() were defined in a different class (and neither class contained the other) then the method capture() could not access the private members of Body.

Comment: If i don't want the field to be accessed by a different instance of the same class, how can i do it? To be clearer, what i'm asking for is something like `private[this]` in Scala

Comment: @jack - If you control the code for the class, one way is to not access that field from other instances.

Comment: @AndyThomas Thanks. Maybe I did not express clearly. I mean, in Scala, if i define as `private[this] Body orbits`, then this `public void capture(Body victim){victim.orbits = this;}` is illegal as `victim.orbits` would not compile, because of the `[this]` after `private` (which is what i want). Then in Java, do we have something like this to achieve?

Comment: @jack - Understood. The Java language does not support compile-time verification of instance-based access control. If you control the class, however, you can effect that control by the code you write in that one class.

Answer (score 1):

Because `victim` is an instance of `Body`, it can access any field of a `Body` isntance.

Answer (score 1):

According to [section 6.6.1 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1):

> Otherwise, if the member or constructor is declared private, then
>   access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the
>   top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or
>   constructor.

Comment: Reference to JLS is the most convincing. That would be my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since `victim` is also of type `Body`, the any instance of `Body` can access the private members of the `victim` instance.

Answer (score 0):

victim is an instance of class Body and has all Attributes of that class. Every instance will have a private property orbits.

If you need a class-Attribute use "private static"