# Why I can not access private field of a base class when private variables can be accessed this way

Tags: c#, java

I was reading question mentioned at links below
[Why are private fields private to the type, not the instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983553/why-are-private-fields-private-to-the-type-not-the-instance)
[Access to private members of class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785289/access-to-private-members-of-class)
[Access private field of a instance object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16510997/access-private-field-of-a-instance-object)

```
public class MyClass : ClassA
    {
        private object myObj;

        public object Field
        {
            get { return myObj; }
            set { myObj = value; }
        }

        public MyClass()
        { 
        }


        public MyClass(MyClass class1)
        {
            class1.myObj = 5;
            this.myObj = class1.myObj;
            class1.myObjOfClassA; // Why I can not access myObjOfClassA when I can access myObj of class1 object
        }
    }


    public class ClassA
    {
        private object myObjOfClassA;

    }
```

My question is
1) If we can access the private variables of Class as mentioned then why a class which extends another class can not access private variables of base class?

2) I believe when code or classes will be compiled then all the methods, variables etc of base class will be added to derived class. Am I right on this?

Comment: 2) Added doesn't mean visible, you are right they are added but they are not visible. `protected` keyword you have to use.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If we can access the private variables of Class as mentioned then why a class which extends another class can not access private variables of base class?

Because the variable isn't declared in the program text of the derived class, which is how private access is defined for Java and C#. (The details around nested classes vary between Java and C#; if you want details for one language or the other, please be more specific in your question.)

> I believe when code or classes will be compiled then all the methods, variables etc of base class will be added to derived class. Am I right on this?

They're not added to the class, no. They're inherited by the derived class, and any *instance* of the derived class will have all the fields that are inherited - but that's not the same as them behaving as if they were *declared* in the derived class.

Comment: +1 - Probably the best person to answer question tagged with both C# and Java

Comment: @Jon Skeet I am asking this question for both the technologies, as you mentioned "details around nested classes vary between Java and C#;" what are those details. and another comment "They're not added to the class, no. They're inherited by the derived class, and any instance of the derived class will have all the fields that are inherited - but that's not the same as them behaving as if they were declared in the derived class". I know this but what happens when the byte code(in case of java) or intermediate assembly code(C#) is generated

Comment: @DeepakBhatia: The inherited fields aren't added to the IL or bytecode of the class either. The JVM/CLR understands the type system, so it knows about inheritance and will do the right thing when constructing objects. As for nested types - I don't think it would make sense to go into those differences in an answer to this question, as it's really a tangent. If you want to know the details, read the specifications first (they're really both fairly easy to read in this regard) and then ask a *specific* question about anything you're still unsure of. Preferably one per language.

Comment: @Jon Skeet thanks. Can you point me to some articles where I can find details about the specifications.